# How can I inherit the Window class in a F# source file

Tags: reference, f#

When scripting it's done like:

```
#light 
#r "System.Xaml.dll"
#r "WindowsBase.dll"
#r "PresentationCore.dll"
#r "PresentationFramework.dll"

open System
open System.Windows

let win = new Window()
win.Title <- "Say Hello"
win.Show()

#if COMPILED
[<STAThread()>]
do 
    let app =  new Application() in
    app.Run() |> ignore
#endif
```

Beneath text for a source file, where I've added System.Xaml, WindowsBase, PresentationCore and PresentationFramework to my references.

```
open System
open System.Windows

let win = new Window()
win.Title <- "Say Hello"
win.Show()

#if COMPILED
[<STAThread()>]
do 
    let app =  new Application() in
    app.Run() |> ignore
#endif
```

I get the message: The type "Window" is not defined. Can anybody tell me how to acces / reference the namespaces System.Windows and System.Windows.Controls from a source file?

Thanks

EDIT: Added screenshot

Before going any further I want to turn the script (with UI) into a source file.

[image: Error: the type 'Window' is not defined]

Comment: Note - this is not inheritance.

Comment: Note, running a fs file within the interactive will not auto add the references for you.  Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Also my source file reference in the solution explorer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Solution Explorer, select the project. On the Project menu, click Add Reference. Or: Project -> Add Reference
2. The Add Reference dialog box opens. Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.

Choose:

```
WindowsBase.dll
PresentationCore.dll
PresentationFramework.dll
System.Xaml.dll
```

Or download template:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com:443/e0907c99-bb04-4eb8-9692-9333d5ff4399

Comment: The question specifically says they've already added these references and are still getting the error...

Comment: Sorry, maybe i misunderstood.                                                          @Funk, could you show screenshots? I still think that you haven't added links.